# AVSpeechSynthesisVoice crashing in iOS 16 beta

Tags: ios, swift, ios16

On iOS 16 beta, the following code is crashing:

```
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")!
```

with the following error code:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It worked fine before and I'm not seeing any API change.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: I'd file a bug with Apple

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are experiencing this in the simulator, but not on actual devices - correct? The reason is that for iOS 16, the devices in the Xcode simulator do not come with any built-in voices, whereas they always used to.

As a result, `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()` returns `[]`, and `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")` returns `nil`.

To solve this, simply download one or more voices to the simulated device you are compiling to. To do that, on the device go to `Settings > Accessibility > Spoken Content > Voices > English`, select a voice, and download it.

Comment: This issue on devices also.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Apple missed to add voice libraries to iOS 16 betas. Below code returns nil.

```
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
```

Which should return the list of available voices. I filed a bug, you should also.